# Getting an error on npm installation for Laravel Breeze - /bin/sh: 1 Cannot fork

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, node-modules, laravel-mix

Trying to install the Laravel Breeze starter kit. First, I'm running `npm install`, then `npm run dev`. Laravel Mix gives me the following error.

> "/bin/sh: 1 Cannot fork".

**Tried the following but it didn't help:**

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
    "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.25",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2"
}
```

**UPD:** Now the error has disappeared for some reason and the console just hangs tightly after the following lines:

```
> dev
> npm run development

> development
> mix
```

Comment: Can you also please share the version of Node and NPM, so it is clear for people looking into this issue.

Comment: Can you check your disk storage? 
df -h

Comment: @Abishek Node version - 14.17.2, npm version - 7.20.0

Comment: @MarioLucki After df -h i have these information: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/10946556?key=126279d1c2a86144d1c6a8bbebf024d4